# Are holidays booked with easyJet entitled to have more cabin baggage allowance than flight only?

Tags: luggage, easyjet

Are easyJet holiday bookings passengers entitled to more allowance on cabin carry on than flight only passengers?

Comment: What would make you think that?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no mention of any difference in allowances in the Easyjet luggage policy http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/baggage/cabin-bag-and-hold-luggage